# How to implement this in Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp

I want to implement a `curl post` in Retrofit 2.0, how can I do that?

```
curl -v -X POST http://example.com/api/oauth/token 
-u "appid:appsecret"  
--data-urlencode "grant_type=authorization_code" 
--data-urlencode "code=zzs88A" 
--data-urlencode "redirect_uri=http://mydomain/show_redirect"
```

Comment: You can see the answer. BTW did you even try something? What is your problem?  As far as I know Retrofit has pretty good documentation http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: I tried Retrofit, but I get server error 500, but in browser everything is fine! Ill test your code and let you know.

Answer (score 3):

I guess something like this:

```
public interface AuthResource {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/oauth/token")
    Response auth(@Header("Authorization") String authorization,
                  @Field("grant_type") String grantType,
                  @Field("code") String code,
                  @Field("redirect_uri") String redirectUri);

}
```

And

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("http://example.com/api")
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .build();

    String basic = "Basic " + Base64.encodeAsString("appid:appsecret");
    Response response = adapter.create(AuthResource.class).auth(
            basic,
            "authorization_code",
            "zzs88A",
            "http://mydomain/show_redirect");
}
```

Comment: Seems this code is for Retrofit 1.9, I am using 2.0

Comment: You can use `java.util.Base64.encodeToString("appid:appsecret".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));` as well

Comment: Retrofit 2.0 still beta, so I used 1.9. There is no big difference in such case, see http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en

Comment: You can simply replace `RestAdapter` with `Retrofit` and remove logger configuration.

Comment: Good, now I get 200OK, but result is empty while in Terminal I get a big JSON >> Response.Body == {}

Comment: Probably some retrofit 2.0 issue or something else, I have no idea. You can edit your question, add more information about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following is what I have done with my project, IMHO, you can refer:

*Using curl:*

```
C:\Users\bnk>curl --data-urlencode "grant_type=password" --data-urlencode "username=bnk" --data-urlencode "password=bnk123" http://myserver/api/token
{"access_token":"UxEXCi_OMXqrY9DWZCh3RMNAPtu0KeaVibj6u8MTPGOSb4G-...vE7nw0KRoT19OE","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":1209599,"userName":"bnk",".issued":"Thu, 12 Nov 2015 01:13:26 GMT",".expires":"Thu, 26 Nov 2015 01:13:26 GMT"}
```

---

*Using Retrofit* (`compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'`)

```
public interface WebAPIService { 
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/api/token")
    void getAccessToken(@Field("grant_type") String grant_type, @Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password, Callback<JSONObject> callback);
}
```

Then inside Activity classes:

```
        // creating a RestAdapter using the custom client
        mRestAdapter =  new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(API_URL_BASE)
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setClient(new OkClient(mOkHttpClient))
                .build();

        WebAPIService webAPIService = mRestAdapter.create(WebAPIService.class);

        Callback callback = new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void success(Object o, Response response) {
                String bodyString = new String(((TypedByteArray) response.getBody()).getBytes());
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, bodyString);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, retrofitError.toString());
            }
        };

        webAPIService.getAccessToken("password", "bnk", "bnk123", callback);
```

Logcat output:

```
11-11 20:25:36.530 11708-11708/com.example.asyncretrofit I/AsyncRetrofit: {"access_token":"cUoWmRZfepS88PJz5lLkog6ojsJnVaH_...DEabubF3dA1USm2kCI","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":1209599,"userName":"bnk",".issued":"Thu, 12 Nov 2015 01:26:55 GMT",".expires":"Thu, 26 Nov 2015 01:26:55 GMT"}
```

Hope this helps!